# Pip broken after uninstalling Python 3.10 with brew

Tags: python, pip

I'm having problems with pip, more specifically that I had installed python 3.10 with brew, after which I uninstalled it and now if I write "pip"

I get this error:

```
❯ pip 
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: no such file or
```

Comment: Do you have something that sets your env variable (a line that starts with `export`) in you `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: nothing related to python

Comment: Then try running `rm -rf /opt/homebrew/bin/pip`

Comment: fyi; you can still use `python3 -m pip install my_package`.

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the folder with

> rm -rf /opt/homebrew/bin/pip

As suggest to Cyao